# How to add a letter in front of file names in a dir when file names have digit(s) at the beginning

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of SVG files in a dir.

```
0.svg 
1.svg 
2.svg ...
42Group.svg 
500px.svg
file1.svg 
file2.svg ...
```

I'd like to add a letter A if a file name starts with a number.

For example, I'd like to change `0.svg` to `A0Solid.svelte`.

Currently I have the following that converts file names:

```
rename -v 's/./\U$&/;s/-(.)/\U$1/g;s/\.svg$/Solid.svelte/' -- *.svg > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But this converts `0.svg` to `0Solid.svelte`. I'd like to change it to `A0Solid.svelte`.

How can I do it with Bash/Shell?

`[Updates]`: I added 42Group.svg 500px.svg to the file names.

Comment: The text says to append the letter `A`, but your code and examples imply that you'd like to also modify the rest of the name by adding `Solid` before the extension. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I think I know how to add Solid before the extension once I change the files with numbers.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `mmv` - I'd start with a dry-run such as `mmv -n -m -p '[0-9]*' 'A#1#2'`, then remove the `-n` when I'm happy with the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, to rename `<digits>.svg` to `A<digits>Solid.svelte`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
```

To `autoload` the `zmv` batch-renaming function (best in `~/.zshrc`)

```
zmv -v '(<->).svg' 'A${1}Solid.svelte'
```

With perl-based renames, you can do the same (though without the safeguards of `zmv`) with:

```
rename -v 's/^(\d+)\.svg\Z/A${1}Solid.svelte/' [0-9]*.svg
```

The `[0-9]*.svg` expands to file names that start with a character in the 0 to 9 range (which includes but in some shells including `bash` is not limited to 0123456789) and end in `.svg`, but `rename` will only rename those that are made only of ASCII decimal digits (0123456789) followed by `.svg`.

Using a `[0-9]*.svg` glob also means the file names won't start with `-`, which means we don't need the `--` which not all variants of `perl`-based `rename` support (while for others, omitting it introduces a command injection vulnerability!). Not all support `-v` either.

If the intent is to capitalise the root names of the files and append `Solid.svelte`, *but also* prepend `A` to file names starting with a digits, for instance for `foo-bar.svg` to become `FooBarSolid.svelte`, `0.svg` `A0Solid.svelte` and `0foo-bar.svg` `A0FooBarSolid.svelte` as your code seems to be trying to do, you'd do:

```
zmv -v '([0-9]#)(*).svg' '${1:+A$1}${${(C)2}//-}Solid.svelte'
```

Or with `rename`:

```
rename -v 's{^\./(\d*)(.*)\.svg\Z}{
    ($1 eq "" ? "" : "A$1") . ($2 =~ s/\w+/\u$&/gr =~ s/-//gr) . "Solid.svelte"
  }ge' ./*.svg
```

Bearing in mind that contrary to `zmv`, it only works properly on ASCII text (no captitalising of `éric` to `Éric` for instance).

Or you can extend the code you already have if you're happy with it by adding `; $_ = "A$_" if /^\d/` to prepend a `A` if the file name starts with a decimal digit.

Comment: This one worked nicely. Thanks. rename -v 's{^\./(\d*)(.*)\.svg\Z}{
    ($1 eq "" ? "" : "A$1") . ($2 =~ s/\w+/\u$&/gr =~ s/-//gr) . "Solid.svelte"
  }ge' ./*.svg

Answer (score 0):

Even complex file renaming can be done using pipeline including while loop with `read`:

```
ls -1 |
    grep '^[0-9]' |
    while read f
    do
        mv -v "$f" "A${f}otherText.svg"
    done
```

(The example above assumes that the names do not contain newlines and maybe few other funny characters.)

Comment: It's also dependant on the current value of `$IFS`. See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: Yes, I could add a note about that. In most cases, I deal with filenames without “funny” characters and therefore I do not need to use IFS. But if I get untrusted or unknown data, I am maybe even overly cautious about such names.

Comment: You would be more likely to avoid problematic names if you just `ls -1 -d [0-9]*` - but it's better to steer clear of parsing the output of `ls`.  You could use `find` instead and handle all names, for example.

Comment: I use `find` quite frequently. And I would recommend against `ls` with glob. A `for` loop with glob would be enough in this case. (`for file in [0-9]*`)